# Can I build a Linux path in Java running on Windows without hard-coding?

Tags: java, linux, windows, windows-10, java-10

I'm using Docker containers to host a Selenium hub and some nodes, and I need to help those tests locate a static HTML file.  I've mapped a folder on my local drive to the Docker nodes.

My code (Java 10, running on Windows 10) looks like this:

```
private URL getTestPageUrl() {
    var folder = Common.getString(Prop.testAssetFolder);
    var pathToTestPage = Paths.get(folder, "selectorTestPage.html");
    URL url = null;
    try { url = pathToTestPage.toUri().toURL(); }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) { /* Most pointlessly checked exception ever. */ }
    return url;
}
```

`pathToTestPage` comes out as `\testAssets\selectorTestPage.html`, which `.toUri().toURL()` then converts to `file:/C:/testAssets/selectorTestPage.html`, which of course doesn't fly on Linux.

Obviously I can just glue together some folder and file names and some hard-coded `/` to get this path in Linux format, but is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use NIO.2's `FileSystemProvider`, specifically [sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystemProvider.java).

That allows you to do something like

```
FileSystemProvider fsp = new UnixFileSystemProvider();
Path path = fsp.getPath(pathToTestPage.toUri());
```

Comment: Is `UnixFileSystemProvider` (or for that matter `LinuxFileSystemProvider`) actually available in the JDK 10 for Windows?  Visual Studio Code, which is usually very good about pulling in the right namespaces, is acting like it isn't there.

Comment: @RyanLundy It's possible it isn't there (the package `sun.nio.fs` does sound like an internal package that you can't rely on to be there). You might need to package it separately if you decide to use it... just wanted to give you the option.

Comment: The sun.nio.fs package is there, but it doesn't seem to include those Unix/Linux classes, as though a compiler flag excludes them or something.  It does include `WindowsFileSystemProvider` and a few abstract classes, which is what makes me wonder whether the others are intentionally excluded in compilation.

Comment: On Java 10 it's possible that the Java module system is hiding that module by default?

Answer (score 0):

If a String result is acceptable, consider combining the power of Paths.get(...) and Apache Commons IO:

```
Path path = Paths.get(folder, "selectorTestPage.html"); 
return FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(path.toString());
```